# How to give a GridView a SearchResultCollection datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, active-directory

I am working on a web application (.net framework 4.0), my application role is to search in the active directory and returns the results in a SearchResultCollection.
My question is how to give my GridView the SearchResultCollection as a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

First check that SearchResultsCollection inherits from IEnumerable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

It does, now you can use the following methods (taken from http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-data-binding-basics.html):

1. **NeedDataSource event - preferred method**

> The key to the advanced data binding of a RadGrid control is handling the NeedDataSource event. RadGrid fires the NeedDataSource event each time it needs to be bound to a data source. If, at the time of the event, the DataSource property is not set to a valid data source object, the grid will not behave correctly.

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource
    ' Ensure that SearchResultsCollection is accessible in your code-behind class or <script runat="server"> code block
    RadGrid1.DataSource = SearchResultsCollection
End Sub
```

2. On Page_Load

> Simple data-binding can be used in simple cases when you do not require the grid to perform complex operations such as: Inserting, deleting, and updating records through custom edit forms (WebUserControl or FormTemplate), Grouping, Hierarchy relations, Filtering, Sorting, Paging

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RadGrid1.DataSource = SearchResultsCollection
End Sub
```

Edit:

Manipulate the results to get the information you need:

```
Private Sub rgItems_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles rgItems.ItemDataBound
    Dim result As SearchResult = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, SearchResult)
    If searchResult IsNot Nothing Then
         ' Get info you need here, perhaps play with result.GetDirectoryEntry()
         ' Assign this data to variables, name, department , etc
         ' Use e.Item.FindControl("ltlDepartment").Text = department 
    End If
End Sub
```

Ensure that you define each one of these controls:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server">
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Department" UniqueName="Department">
        <ItemTemplate>      
            <asp:Literal id="ltlDepartment" runat="server" />  
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</telerik:radGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution shows me In the GridView one column: Path (exp:LDAP://tetracom/CN=Said Fares,OU=Enterprise Networking Department= Sales,OU=Tetracom Users and Computers,DC=tetracom,DC=com,DC=lb)
I want my GridView to show me many Columns: Name, Department,... (Exp: Name: Said Fares, Department: Sales, ... )